# Knockout 3.2 Components - can't access component viewModel root inside foreach binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-components

Using knockout's new 3.2 Component spec, I'm trying to create a component with a foreach binding inside of it that renders a collection of objects. The objects inside the foreach binding need to have access to attributes on the component's VM, but seem to loose that reference once in the foreach loop.

Is there a simple way to directly access the root of a component's view model inside its template?

**Component VM:**

```
function RelatedCompaniesViewModel(params) {
    var self = this;

    self.companies = params.companies;
    self.displayLimit = ko.observable(3);

}
```

**Component Template:**

```
<!-- ko foreach: companies() -->
    <li data-bind="visible: $index() < displayLimit()">
       ...more bindings...
    </li>
<!-- /ko -->

(returns a "displayLimit is not defined" error)
```

Comment: Similar to previous methods use one of the available [binding context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) properties. In this particular case [$parent](http://jsfiddle.net/w0vgfrbw/) or `$root`  will work.

Comment: *facepalm* didn't even know the $parent context existed. The entire module listed above is nested inside another component so $root wouldn't work. Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `displayLimit()` to `$parent.displayLimit()`.

**Component Template:**

```
<!-- ko foreach: companies() -->
    <li data-bind="visible: $index() < $parent.displayLimit()">
       ...more bindings...
    </li>
<!-- /ko -->
```